# Get selected option text selenium VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I am trying not to select an option from drop-down menu but to get or return the already selected option
I have something like that

```
Set eleClass = .FindElementByName("oo10").AsSelect
```

I tried to get the option with using `.Value` and `.Text` but this doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I could figure it out

```
Debug.Print eleClass.SelectedOption.Text
```